# Which disease is this combination of medicine is used for?

Tags: practice-of-medicine, cough

I have had a cough form in several days. 
My doctor had given me some medication for this.

But when I searched for the medication used it made me confused, because the medications given commonly work on asthma.

The Medication is:
1. Rapitus Plus (syrup)
2. Cap. Nuipenta-D
3. Deflazacort (MAHACORT-DZ 6)
4. Fix-AR

Can anyone tell me if he has given the right medication?

Comment: You said you have cough but you did not say if your doctor made any tests and say what was the cause of cough. Common cold, bronchitis, asthma, allergies and pneumonia all cause cough but require different treatments, so nobody can tell you if the above medicines are good for you or not.

Comment: @Jan till now no test we had done. He just checked by hearbeat and given mediines

Comment: @Jan [<please do not answer in the comments>](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/378/should-answers-in-comments-be-immediately-deleted) If you have an answer, please leave it below, with references back it up. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

- [Rapitus Plus (syrup)](http://www.gmedication.com/?s=rapitus%20plus) consist of:

  1. Chlorphenamine(antihistamine)-relieves itching, sneezing, watery eyes or runny nose associated with common cold or flu.
  2. Levodropropizine(antiussive)- helps coughs
- [Cap. Nuipenta-D](http://www.mims.com/india/drug/info/nupenta-d/nupenta-d%20cap)- Antacids, Antireflux Agents & Antiulcerants
- [Deflazacort (MAHACORT-DZ 6)](http://drugbook.in/mahacort-dz-66mg.html)- Allergic And Inflammatory Disorders
- [Fix-AR](https://www.1mg.com/drugs/fixar-10mg-120mg-tablet-311860):

> Montelukast is used to prevent and treat asthma, seasonal and year
>   round allergies (hay fever), and prevent exercise-induced asthma.

We can not tell you if the medication is wrong, as I am not your doctor and did not prescribe it. However, the medication seems indicated for the symptoms. Your doctor probably associated your cough with possible allergies or Asthma, excluding the Nuipenta. To better understand you can:

- Ask your doctor for papers on your meds
- Ask them why a medication was prescribed
- How it will affect you

As a patient you are entitled to his care and most times it is given.